# CKEditor text area is blank in rails 3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to embedd a ckeditor into a form and it just comes up blank. The text area is just an empty space where I expect to find an html editor window. I have a model where I want the "description" field to be html text. I thought it would be convenient to use ckeditor to edit it. I can't work out why the text field editor is not showing.

I've got a rails 3.1 app, and I'm using the ckeditor gem (version 3.6.2). I've downloaded ckeditor and put it in my assets/javascripts folder.

In my application.html.erb file I have this line:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %>
```

In my view I have some code like this:

```
<%= form_for(@k) do |f| %>
<%= f.cktext_area :description, :toolbar => 'Full', :width => 800, :height => 400 %>
```

This generates html like this:

```
<textarea id="k_description" rows="20" name="k[description]" cols="40"  style="visibility: hidden;"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (CKEDITOR.instances['k_description']) {CKEDITOR.remove(CKEDITOR.instances['k_description']);}CKEDITOR.replace('k_description', { height: 400,language: 'en',toolbar: 'Full',width: 800 });
//]]>
</script>
```

It all looks like it should work, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to remove the :toolbar option. It doesn't seem to be user friendly. I've found you have to enclose options in double brackets to customize it, like `f.cktext_area :description, :ckeditor => {toolbar: [['Bold']]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way CKeditor links its dependancies you'll have to move it to the public folder. There is a helper option coming in Rails 3.1.1 which I believe will fix this problem. (:digest => false).

Comment: I moved the ckeditor folder out of assets/javascripts and put it in public/javascripts. This didn't solve my problem. The text area was no longer blank, but it was just an ordinary text area, not an html editor. I then tried putting ckeditor in BOTH places, and suddenly everything then seemed to work. I look forward to a proper fix for this problem in rails 3.1.1!

Comment: I would have a look at using the non-gem version of CKEditor and use the included jquery code to attach the editor instance to the text areas (via a css class). I think this approach is a bit simpler and allow you to keep up with the latest CKEditor code fixes. I don't think the GEM is 3.1 compatible yet.