# CKEditor/vendor library: can it work when in vendor folder instead of public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I have a working edit view to which I'm trying to add CKEditor. I've downloaded the CKEditor folder/files and placed them in `my_app/vendor/assets/ckeditor/`. I'm using Rails 4 and this folder is included in the asset pipeline. To application.js I've added `//= require ckeditor.js` and to application.css `@import "contents";`.

In my edit view I have (I'd like to use the [inline option](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline)):

```
<%= f.text_area :page, contenteditable: 'true' %>
<script>
  CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
  CKEDITOR.inline( 'image_page' );
</script>
```

*Problem*: Now when loading the edit view, the text field is not displayed as an editable field but just as plain text. There's no way to edit this text and no sign of CKEditor. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The page's source code that is being generated, includes:

```
<textarea contenteditable="true" name="image[page]" id="image_page">
  Arbor cubo vel.
</textarea>
<script>
  CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
  CKEDITOR.inline( 'image_page' );
</script>
```

---

**Update:** I got it working by moving the CKEditor files from the vendor folder to the public folder. **Could someone perhaps confirm whether or not CKEditor is compatible with the asset pipeline?**

I would prefer to place it in the vendor folder if anyway possible. [This old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7638378/) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304386) refer to something similar (if I place `<% var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/ckeditor/'; %>` as a header line in `application.html.erb` my app crashes with the error `dynamic constant assignment '.freeze`). Could someone with more experience with CKEditor provide a more definitive answer than these old posts?

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in your browser console?

Comment: Yes, there's one: `TypeError: c[a] is undefined` referring to `ckeditor.self-ac8eb64d6310b5150b01ee8f07fa450e7e918307c7688139a9fa9050baf7413d.js:226:27`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `ckeditor` assets under either `vendor/assets/javascripts` for the JavaScript files and `vendor/assets/stylesheets` for the CSS files (separate the ckeditor assets among those folders)

The whenever an asset is referring to another asset use the `asset-url` helper instead of `url` so that this asset is served through the asset pipeline

You also need to include all the assets that you'll put in `vendor....` folders in the asset pipeline by `//require` or `import`

On a side not you can use the ckeditor gem https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor it will save you a lot of time also it handles some features out of the box like images upload and gallery of ckeditor

Comment: Thanks @bigsolomon. I prefer not to use the gem and keep the control myself. So, then the only way to include ckeditor in the asset pipeline is to edit all the references...? This of course creates problems in that 1) when upgrading to a new version of ckeditor, it is necessary to edit all references again, 2) the js file is minimized. I have also posted a more general question on this subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32544035

Comment: This is the only way as far as I know if you want all the assets to be served through asset-pipeline, you can use live compilation `config.assets.compile = true` in your environment config if you want to compile assets on production server when they are requested but it's not generally recommended.

Answer (score 1):

May be the script is executing before the textarea is fully loaded on the DOM. Try to use a post load wrapper to your script like the jquery's:

```
$(function(){
   // ... your code
})
```

Comment: Thanks @NachPD. Would you say something like this?: `$(id='image_page').ready(function () {`  `CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;`  `CKEDITOR.inline( 'image_page' );`  `});`. Unfortunately, with this code the bevavior is still that sometimes it loads the text field with the ckeditor and sometimes without. Often when I first go from an index view to the edit view that has the ckeditor in it, the ckeditor isn't there. When reloading the edit page, the ckeditor is always there. The source code of the page is the same, irrespective whether is has or hasn't loaded the ckeditor.

Comment: I have the idea that `ckeditor.js` is perhaps not yet ready loading or something. Because if I also include this file in the index view I spoke of (even though this index view doesn't use this js file), then when going to the edit view the ckeditor does seem to load correctly at all times. Should I perhaps somehow ensure that `ckeditor.js` gets loaded first? (I'm loading the file in the body instead of the header)